# Java : Couldn't understand method Syntax 

Tags: java

I am working on an existing code. In one of the classes I have this method, with the folowing syntax:

```
public Response getData(Request serviceRequest, Class<? extends APIResponse> expectedResponseClass) 
{

}
```

My question is, I couldn't understand the second parameter of this method.

Could anybody please tell me, what is that second parameter, and how should we must understand that?

Thank you!

Modified as to prove that we can pass the subclass also as a parameter  to a method which expects superclass

**Superclass.java**

```
 public class Superclass {}
```

**One.java**

```
public class One extends Superclass{}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        One one = new One();
        Main main = new Main();
        main.mainMethod(one);
    }

    public void mainMethod(Superclass sc) {
        System.out.println("Inside the Main Method");
    }

}
```

Comment: It's called generics. Have a read here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method's parameter type were `Class<APIResponse>`, that would indicate a `Class` object whose type parameter was `APIResponse`—not any subclass of it. A `Class` object's type parameter is the class that it represents. In other words, the only valid parameter would be the `APIResponse` class object (or `null`).

By contrast, `Class<? extends APIResponse>` indicates a `Class` object whose type parameter is `APIResponse` *or any subclass of it*. That means that if you have a subclass of `APIResponse` (I'll call it `MyAPIResponse`), you can pass its class object to this method. That object's type is `Class<MyAPIResponse>`, which fits inside `Class<? extends APIResponse>`.

You may be wondering why this is so. Why can't you put a `Class<MyAPIResponse>` object into a `Class<APIResponse>` variable? The answer is because it would break Java's type safety. This isn't immediately obvious, and I can't explain it in terms of `Class` (that class doesn't have any methods with parameters depending on its type parameter), so instead I'll give an example using a different generic class: `ArrayList`. Here `YourAPIResponse` is another subclass of `APIResponse`.

```
ArrayList<APIResponse> list = new ArrayList<MyAPIResponse>();
list.add(new YourAPIResponse());
```

If an `ArrayList<MyAPIReponse>` object could fit into an `ArrayList<APIResponse>` variable, then this code would compile—but the effect would be to insert a `YourAPIResponse` object into a `List<MyAPIResponse>`, thereby breaking Java's type safety. And that's why you can't do that.

This obviously puts a lot of limits on what you can do with pure generics. To get around this, wildcard generics were invented. So you can do this:

```
ArrayList<? extends APIResponse> list = new ArrayList<MyAPIResponse>();
```

But if you were to then add the second line from above, it wouldn't compile, because the compiler can't verify that the runtime type of the argument fits inside the type parameter of the `ArrayList`. And so type safety is preserved.

Answer (score 5):

`Class<? extends APIResponse>` is an example of a **bounded wildcard**. This means that it could be a class of type `APIResponse` itself, or some subclass of it.

If you had `Class<APIResponse>` instead, the method could only be called on classes of type `APIResponse`, not any of its subtypes.

Take a look at the [Wildcards tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) for more information.

Comment: I'll add that the above method can be called e.g. with such arguments:
getData(serviceRequest, APIResponse.class)

Comment: I wont agree on the point , instead, the method could only be called on classes of type APIResponse, not any of its subtypes. I have tried a simple example , in which i could able to pass the subclass

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is an instance of type [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) that corresponds to a subclass of `APIResponse` (or to `APIResponse` itself).

Note that there is no instance of `APIResponse` (or a subclass) involved in this call, as you seem to imply in some comments.

Answer (score 0):

That's a [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) parameter. It means that the second parameter should be a [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) which class extends the `APIResponse`.

Comment: Thank you very much , but why this way ?? can't we directly use the super class as the second parameter directly ?? rather than all these nonsense syntax

Comment: That would be too strict, you can create your own `Class` which extends the `APIResponse` and implement it as you want.

Comment: Could you please tell me why did you used the word "That would be too strict" because i feel there is no difference between the two approaches ??

Answer (score 0):

It denotes that the second parameter can be any subclass of APIResponse.